# Register Your V2.0 Application

Tags: stackexchange-api

Я хочу зарегистрировать свое приложение на https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register/submit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне надо указать ссылку на иконку в поле

Application icon

В плейс холдере написанно, что она должна располагаться на Stack Exchange imgur account

У меня есть учётная запись на imgur но ссылки от неё не подходят.

Как мне добавить иконку на Stack Exchange imgur account ?